# OptaPlanner score corruption with custom shadow variable calculation based on chained variable

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm struggling with score corruption problem.

My case is based on timed customer vehicle routing example - I have a list of schedule allocations which are to start on particular metro stations and a list of employees (inspectors) who should visit them and do some work. The goal is allocate all tasks to these employees and to minimize transfers between the allocations.

I have set up a chained variable `previousSlot`, and added a custom shadow variable `shadowStartTime` which is supposed to be calculated based on the previous assignment.

Here is the planning entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Allocation implements ScheduleSlot {
    @AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousSlot")
    private Inspector inspector;

    @PlanningVariable(
        graphType=PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED, 
        valueRangeProviderRefs={"inspector_range", "task_range"} )
    private ScheduleSlot previousSlot;

    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = SlotUpdateVariableListerer.class,
        sources = { 
            @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "inspector"),
            @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousSlot") })
    private Long shadowStartTime;

    ...
```

Here, `Inspector` is a planning fact which is also an anchor, and `ScheduleSlot` is interface common to inspectors and allocations.

Variable listener is pretty simple too:

```
public class SlotUpdateVariableListerer implements VariableListener<ScheduleProblemSolution, ScheduleSlot> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<ScheduleProblemSolution> scoreDirector, ScheduleSlot slot) {
        updateTask(scoreDirector, slot);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<ScheduleProblemSolution> scoreDirector, ScheduleSlot slot) {
        updateTask(scoreDirector, slot);
    }

    private void updateTask(ScoreDirector<ScheduleProblemSolution> scoreDirector, ScheduleSlot slot) {
        ScheduleSlot prevSlot = slot.getPreviousSlot();
        final Long startTime = prevSlot != null ? prevSlot.getFinishTime() + prevSlot.timeToNext(slot) : null;

        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(slot, "shadowStartTime");
        ((Allocation)slot).setShadowStartTime(startTime);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(slot, "shadowStartTime");
    }
}
```

And this fails if number of allocations > 2 right on the construction heuristics phase:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> VariableListener corruption after completedAction ([09:00:00,
> 09:31:44] Task 321652 ...):
> The entity ([10:37:16, 11:14:24] Task 320522...)'s shadow variable (Allocation.shadowStartTime)'s corrupted value (1659940628000) changed
> to uncorrupted value (1659944236000) after all VariableListeners were
> triggered without changes to the genuine variables.

What could be wrong here?

UPD: Added a stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
VariableListener corruption after completedAction (...):
The entity (...)'s shadow variable (Allocation.shadowStartTime)'s corrupted value (...) changed to uncorrupted value (...) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
  Maybe the VariableListener class (SlotUpdateVariableListerer) for that shadow variable (Allocation.shadowStartTime) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed.

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:520)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractPhaseScope.java:160)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.predictWorkingStepScore(AbstractPhase.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.doStep(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:82)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:69)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:83)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:193)
    at com.iconsoft.metro.opt.solver.ScheduleProblemSolution.solve(ScheduleProblemSolution.java:203)
    at com.iconsoft.metro.opt.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

UPD-2: Looks like this happens after anchor's entity reallocation:

```
23:56:43.328 DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (226), score (-59init/-5hard/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task 320522: (uninitialized) {null -> Inspector #0}).
23:56:43.362 DEBUG     CH step (1), time spent (260), score (-58init/-4hard/0soft), selected move count (7), picked move (Task 320527: (uninitialized) {null -> Inspector #1}).
23:56:43.396 DEBUG     CH step (2), time spent (294), score (-57init/-3hard/0soft), selected move count (8), picked move (Task 321652: (uninitialized) {null -> Inspector #2}).
...
23:56:43.743 DEBUG     CH step (8), time spent (641), score (-51init/-10hard/0soft), selected move count (14), picked move (Task 326806: (uninitialized) {null -> Inspector #0})
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption after completedAction()...
```

But I'm still unclear what does it mean...

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention - I'm using TABU search with nearby selection and the problem appears in FULL_ASSERT mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shadow start time of the **input** problem is incorrect, so already at the start of the solver. If that's true, check the stacktrace of the FULL_ASSERT error, it will contain phaseStarted().

If that's true, our error message could explain this better.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't see phaseStarted() in the stack trace (added it to the post above). Actually, this variable is private to the Allocation class and therefore it's null at the start.

Comment: I noticed that it happens right after an anchor entity (Inspector) gets reallocated to another task. But all of them have absolutelly the same base date, so I still have no clue...

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sources` attribute of your `@CustomShadowVariable`.

Maybe some of the genuine/shadow variables it depends on are missing in the @CustomShadowVariable's sources value.

Comment: In the error message, we'll want to add a "maybe" line for this. Creating a PR.

Comment: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/2197

Comment: This shadow variable depends on two sources: `previousSlot`, which is a chained planning variable feeded from 2 ranges ("inspector_range", "task_range"), and an `inspector` anchor shadow variable, which, in turn, depends on `previousSlot` too. See the code above.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, I fear. Debugging is your friend, as is TRACE logging. If FULL_ASSERT is on, use a different assertionScoreDirectorFactory (for example an EasyScoreCalculator) or you'll hit breakpoints in debugging for both the working score director as well as the assertion score director.

Comment: BTW, what's `slot.clearPreviousSlotChange();` That looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of experiments I figured out that the score corruption happens when a custom shadow variable gets changed without any change to corresponding genuine variable.

It looks like the OptaPlanner might call a shadow variable listener even if a genuine variable don't change and any change during this call would cause a failure.

So, I've added some code to wrap this out:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Allocation implements ScheduleSlot {
    private ScheduleSlot previousSlot;
    private ScheduleSlot _previousSlot;

    @PlanningVariable(
        graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED, 
        valueRangeProviderRefs = { "inspector_range", "task_range" } )
    public ScheduleSlot getPreviousSlot() {
        return previousSlot;
    }
    public void setPreviousSlot(ScheduleSlot previousSlot) {
        this._previousSlot = this.previousSlot;
        this.previousSlot = previousSlot;
    }
    public boolean isPreviousSlotChanged() { 
        return _previousSlot != previousSlot; 
    };
    public void clearPreviousSlotChange() {
        _previousSlot = previousSlot;
    };
}

public class SlotUpdateVariableListerer implements VariableListener<ScheduleProblemSolution, ScheduleSlot> {
    ...
    private void updateTask(ScoreDirector<ScheduleProblemSolution> scoreDirector, ScheduleSlot slot) {
        if (slot.isPreviousSlotChanged() && slot instanceof Allocation) {
            final Long startTime = prevSlot != null ? prevSlot.getFinishTime() + prevSlot.timeToNext(this) : null;
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(slot, "shadowStartTime");
            ((Allocation)slot).setShadowStartTime(startTime);
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(slot, "shadowStartTime");
            slot.clearPreviousSlotChange();
         }
    }
}
```

And now it works. There's another problem, with UndoMove corruption, but this one is for another thread.

BTW, I have created a [repo](https://github.com/skolchin/optaplanner-score-creep) with reproducible example and the fix, hope it'll be useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

That `slot.isPreviousSlotChanged()` check and `slot.clearPreviousSlotChange();` look fishy.

An allocation can have its inspector changed without having it's previous slot changed. It can even have it previous's previous slot changed without having its previous slot changed.

Consider A2 in the following case:

```
A -> A1 -> A2 -> A3
B -> B1 -> B2
changed to
A -> A3
B -> B1 -> A1 -> A2 -> B2
```

Comment: Agree, and now it seems that the problem reappears in UndoMove corruption :( Is there any other ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Not without a code review (see Red Hat's support subscription) I fear. Either way, it's a separate question, this one is long enough.